# Limit of a subsequence implies limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Question: *Let $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a monotone sequence such as $x_n \geq x_{n+1}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$* Assume $\{x_{{n}_{k}}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Show that if $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{{n}_{k}}=a$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{{n}}=a$.

What I have by far: Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Using the definition, we have $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{{n}_{k}}=a$ equivalent to $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such as $|x_{{n}_{k}} - a|<\varepsilon, \forall n\geq n_0.$
By hypothesis, $\{x_{{n}_{k}}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq \{x_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, so, we'll have $|x_{n} - a|<\varepsilon, \forall n\geq n_0.$ Which implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{{n}}=a$.

So I'm struggling with the lack of use of one of the hypothesis: *let $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a monotone sequence such as $x_n \geq x_{n+1}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$*

Can someone give me a hand over this?

Comment: i think you mean: Using the definition, we have $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{{n}_{k}}=a$ equivalent to $\exists k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such as $|x_{{n}_{k}} - a|<\varepsilon, \forall k\geq k_0.$

Comment: Consider the sequence $0,1,0,1,…$ with the convergent subsequence $1,1,1,…$. Where does your proof fail?

Comment: @MartinR That's what I came here to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W.L.O.G let, $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an increasing sequence.

To prove $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent, it is enough to show $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded above. (Why?)

Since, $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{{n}_{k}}=a$ , one thing is clear , if
$\{x_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge, it must converge to $a$.

As we know a increasing sequence in $\Bbb{R}$ which is convergent, must converge to the sup of the set consisting the terms of the sequence.

With the above motivation, we claim that , $$x_n\le a$$ for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$

Prove by contradiction, suppose there is one $n_0 \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $x_n> a$

As $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is increasing sequence,

$$x_{m}> a $$ for all $m\ge n_0$

Now It's your task to contradict that $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{{n}_{k}}=a$.